# syntax for LIKE keyword in PHP using a variable

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-like

Basically this is the code I am using:

```
$batch = "XZ";
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT day FROM course WHERE course_id LIKE "%'.$batch.'" AND table_name=?');
$query->execute([$_SESSION['table_name']]);
```

and I am getting output as NULL;

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Did you start the session?

Comment: Does the query work if you manually execute it?

Comment: What does `var_dump('SELECT day FROM course WHERE course_id LIKE "%'.$batch.'" AND table_name=?', $_SESSION['table_name'])` return? You should bind the variable but that probably isnt your issue here.

Comment: This code isn't getting any output. The code should be a [mcve] which should include all relevant information like how you are retrieving the data from your result and variables. Are you getting any rows returned? Do any rows exist? Do any rows have `course_id` ending with `XZ` and a corresponding `table_name`? What is `table_name`? If you echo out the query and run it in another tool like PHPMyAdmin against the database directly do you get any rows?

Comment: You are poorly using the prepare() function since you are not using a placeholder (assuming this is user provided data).  There a existing answers on SO that show how to use LIKE with prepared statements.

Comment: @chris85 yes the session is started already and I am not getting any error being reported..

Comment: @mickmackusa Mysql doesn't really care about single or double quotes. And they are using a placeholder for one value, but not the other.

Comment: @Daniel query does works perfectly when i execute it manually in MySQL console.But when i execute it in in PHP,its not working.I think there is an error in syntax

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I am not getting any rows returned.yes I have rows course_id ending with XZ and table_name is also correct .                   
 How can i run query in PHPMyadmin using variables..??

Comment: You can't using the php variables from this page, but you could echo the query as a string here and run that.

Comment: yes everything is fine as I am using these variables in other queries also.The only problem here is using php variables with "LIKE" keyword.I think there is a syntax error on that.@mickmackusa

Comment: `DAY` is a keyword, I would backtick-wrap it as a matter of good practice.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html  Are there queries executing before this one?  More code to consider?

Comment: @mickmackusa I am getting correct output in PHPMyAdmin also,If i dont specify PHP variables within it.

Comment: At this point, we are just guessing.  There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the details you have provided.  Without any new information, your question is likely to be closed as "not reproduce-able".  Perhaps show us some table structure/data and show us the actual output of the variables involved.  Show use the bool result of each function call.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn It does care about single vs. double quotes if ANSI_QUOTES mode is on.

Comment: @marcus_fenix did you try it with the quoting swapped around?